# Quartz Frequency Selection for STM32F334K8T6

Tags: stm32, oscillator

The frequency of the built-in HSE [STM32](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f334k8.pdf) generator has a range of 4-32mHz.

On many boards, I saw a crystal at 32.768mHz.

Tell me, is it possible to use crystal oscillators with a different frequency?
For example, 16 or 25 mHz. Is this normal mode?

As far as I understand, the frequency at 32mHz is worse than the frequency of 16 or 25mHz in terms of noise immunity of the device.

Comment: Milli Hz? [padding]

Comment: You are mixing up processor clock and timekeeping (RTC) clocks.  Without details of your application it is unclear that you cannot simple use the approximate internal clock.  And you may want the PLL.  This is really not answerable, if you need to commit to a board today place both a 32.768 KHz LSE and a footprint which can support either 8 or 16 MHz HSE and decide later what to actually populate/use.  Also see what is on the Nucleo or other EVB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Indeed, I made a mistake.

Having studied the information that I found out:
LSE is an external generator necessary for RTC to work. Its frequency is 32.768kHz.

Comment: For the main operation of the microcontroller, either an internal 8 MHz LSI generator is used (the microcontroller is launched from it) or external with a certain frequency range (indicated in the specification). I chose 8 MHz.

After that, this frequency is multiplied in x2 ... x16 multiples using the PLL multiplier. As a result, we can adjust the frequency of the microcontroller (a maximum of 128 MHz is reached for 8 MHz).